# How to make a filter selection dependent on the selection of another filter with the JVX Framework?

Tags: jvx

I have a screen in my project with some filters (dropdown list) and I want to make the selection of some filters depending on the selection of a specific filter.

I have unfortunately not found a method for the filter to do this, but know it is possible with the JVX Framework.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, you have two options: Use foreign key references with overlaping columns. If foreign keys are correct defined, dependent values will be filtered automatically.

It's also possible to change values manually. Simply listen for valueChanged on editor A and set an additional filter condition for linked cell editor of B and C. To access the cell editor, simply call:

```
((ILinkedCellEditor)UICellEditor.getCellEditor(A.getUIResource())).setAdditionalCondition(condition);
```

The additional condition will be applied to the original filter with `and` operator.

The `A.getUIResource()` is needed with current JVx but future versions will work with `A` only.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I chose the option with ValueChanged and it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So, you have 3 linked cell editors (A, B, C) and if A is set to a specific value, B and C should show a pre-defined value?

If this is what you want, then use `eventFilterValueChanged` of your filter A and call `setValue(Object)` or `setAllValues(Object[])` for B and C.

If you mean that the available values of B and C depend on selected value of A (dependent linked cell editors), then it's more complex?

If your filters automatically search `isAutoSearch()` then, every filter value change will trigger fetching. Could be a performance problem.

Comment: The selection of filters should depend on the other filters.

So filter B should depend on the selection of filter A and filter C should depend on the selection fo filter B. For example, filter A filters by countries and filter B should then show only cities for this country and filter C then only districts for this city.