# How can i set a condition to a filter editor which is an ILinkedCellEditor

Tags: jvx

I have a filter editor which is an ILinkedCellEditor in on of my screens. I need to set filter in some cases to restrict the list.

How can i do that?

It's not working when i set the filter on the linked cell editor from the remote data book.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The condition will be set by the linked cell editor itself if you open it because it's possible to "search". Every search will change the filter.

So you should set an additional condition as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76332272/how-to-make-a-filter-selection-dependent-on-the-selection-of-another-filter-with)